# What packages are required to play .mp3 files in Chromium?

Tags: chromium, mp3, codecs

I have the following packages installed.

```
ubuntu-restricted-extras
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

Howevever, I still cannot play `.mp3` files in Chromium.

Example: https://degrowthaudiobook.wordpress.com/

In Chrome, this page displays properly the playback controls. In Chromium, however, it does not display the playback controls but only a black bar.